# Causes for inefficient I/O?

Tags: rsync, performance, file-copy, io

I'm `rsync`'ing a huge folder from an external to an internal 3,5" HDD, both 5.400 rpm. When using `dstat` to have a look at the current throughput, I regularly see patterns like this:

```
--total-cpu-usage-- -dsk/total- -net/total- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai stl| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw 
 20   6  34  40   0|  98M   90M|1272B 3652B|   0     0 |1702  4455 
 21   6  37  37   0| 121M   90M|1646B 4678B|   0     0 |2057  6488 
 17  24  29  30   0|  77M   95M| 630B 2416B|   0     0 |1581  4644 
 20   5  33  43   0|  86M   84M|1372B 2980B|   0     0 |1560  4146 
 20   6  30  44   0|  80M   75M| 700B 2722B|   0     0 |1484  3942 
 11   2  47  39   0|  39M   65M| 642B 1332B|   0     0 | 765  1507 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0    91M|  70B  354B|   0     0 | 136    70 
  0   0  50  49   0|   0    71M| 306B  346B|   0     0 | 146   119 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0    83M|  70B  346B|   0     0 | 145    60 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0     0 |  70B  346B|   0     0 |  36    84 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0     0 | 164B  646B|   0     0 |  35    71 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0     0 | 140B  802B|   0     0 |  30    64 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0     0 |  70B  346B|   0     0 |  27    68 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0    34M| 134B  346B|   0     0 |  86    68 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0     0 |  70B  346B|   0     0 |  30    71 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0     0 |2320B  346B|   0     0 |  40    76 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0     0 |  70B  346B|   0     0 |  29    71 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0     0 |  70B  346B|   0     0 |  25    50 
 -----------------------------[snip]------------------------------
  0   0  50  50   0|   0     0 |2230B  346B|   0     0 |  35    61 
  0   0  50  50   0|   0    60M|  70B  346B|   0     0 | 118    83 
  1   7  42  50   0| 256k  104M| 230B  500B|   0     0 | 281   480 
 21   5  31  42   0| 117M   76M|1120B 3392B|   0     0 |1849  4309 
 23   5  36  36   0| 137M   56M|1202B 3958B|   0     0 |2149  5782 
 24   5  36  35   0| 138M  100M|1284B 4112B|   0     0 |2174  6021
```

Say, for several seconds up to a minute, both read and write throughput drop to zero. What's the bottleneck here?

I mean, since both drives are about the same speed, none of them should be idle for too long. Even further, at least one drive should be always reading or writing. What is the system waiting for?

System is idle, only thing eating cpu is the `rsync` task. Memory is 8GB, CPU is a 7th-gen i5 quad-core. The internal HDD is hooked via SATA to the mainboard, a Gigabyte G170X-Ultra Gaming. Filesystem is ext4 in both cases, encrypted with dmcrypt/LUKS on the internal (write) side. Might that be the cause? If so, how to check the performance of dmcrypt? I see, CPU is 50% idle 50% waiting when the transfer drops occur. What may I conclude from that?

It's an up-to-date-Archlinux with kernel version `4.13.11-1-ARCH`. Anything to look out for? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** `iotop` was pointed out to be more accurate than `dstat`. Unfortunately, `iotop` shows zero thoughput as well when `dstat` drops to zero. I've done a [screencast](https://vimeo.com/241339098) to show it.

Comment: I think your external hdd is not in the best condition.

Comment: You can try to grab a stack trace of your `rsync` process during an IO pause to get some data on what it's trying to do at that time.  FWIW, `rsync` is an extremely inefficient way to transfer data - it has to do a lot of IO operations just to identify what needs to be synced before even starting to copy data.  Something like ZFS send/receive of incremental snapshots is much more efficient because the filesystem keeps track of changes as they are made - there's no crawling two entire filesystems trying to *find* what needs to be sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 sets of tools to get some block-level device statistics. The first is [iolatency](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/master/iolatency) from Brendan Gregg's [perf tools](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools). It produces a simple histogram of disk operation latency such as:

```
>=(ms) .. <(ms)   : I/O      |Distribution                          |
     0 -> 1       : 1913     |######################################|
     1 -> 2       : 438      |#########                             |
     2 -> 4       : 100      |##                                    |
     4 -> 8       : 145      |###                                   |
     8 -> 16      : 43       |#                                     |
    16 -> 32      : 43       |#                                     |
    32 -> 64      : 1        |#                                     |
```

Another script in the toolset is `iosnoop` which shows commands and their operations, eg:

```
COMM         PID    TYPE DEV      BLOCK        BYTES     LATms
/usr/bin/mon 31456  R    8,0      9741888      4096       2.14
/usr/bin/mon 31456  R    8,0      9751408      4096       0.16
/usr/bin/mon 31456  R    8,0      20022728     4096       1.44
/usr/bin/mon 31456  R    8,0      19851752     4096       0.26
jbd2/sda3-41 416    WS   8,0      130618232    65536      1.89
jbd2/sda3-41 416    WS   8,0      209996928    65536      1.92
jbd2/sda3-41 416    WS   8,0      210006528    8192       1.94
```

Then there is the [blktrace](http://fibrevillage.com/storage/531-how-to-use-blktrace-and-btt-to-debug-and-tune-disk-io-on-linux) package which records low-level block operations with `blktrace` and then shows all sorts of information with `blkparse`, and many other commands, including the simple summary from `btt` ([pdf user guide](http://www.fis.unipr.it/doc/blktrace-1.0.1/btt.pdf)):

```
$ sudo blktrace /dev/sda  # ^C to stop
=== sda ===
  CPU  0:                  180 events,        9 KiB data
  CPU  1:                 1958 events,       92 KiB data
  Total:                  2138 events (dropped 0),      101 KiB data
$ ls -ltra # one file per cpu
-rw-r--r--    1 root   root       8640 Nov  5 10:16 sda.blktrace.0
-rw-r--r--    1 root   root      93992 Nov  5 10:16 sda.blktrace.1
$ blkparse -O -d combined.output  sda.blktrace.*  # combine cpus
$ btt -i combined.output 
    ALL           MIN           AVG           MAX           N
Q2Q               0.000001053   0.106888548   6.376503027         253
Q2G               0.000000795   0.000002266   0.000011060         184
G2I               0.000000874   0.000979485   0.002588781         328
Q2M               0.000000331   0.000000599   0.000002716          70
I2D               0.000000393   0.000480112   0.002435491         328
M2D               0.000002044   0.000028418   0.000126845          70
D2C               0.000080986   0.001925224   0.010111418         254
Q2C               0.000087025   0.002603157   0.010120629         254
...
```

D2C, for example, is how long it takes the hardware device to do an operation.

You might also run `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` on each disc to see if there are any failures showing.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `dstat` uses I/O statistics on the file descriptor level i.e. the application calls `write()`, and as soon as the syscall returns the data which `dstat` sees increases.

But that does not mean that the data has actually been written. I guess that these seeming pauses are the phases in which the buffers are written to the block device. It makes sense that during these times the I/O wait value is even higher than during the phases in which `dstat` measures data transfer.

`iotop` tells apart writes to and reads from the disk and the cache. Maybe that tool can deliver interesing additional information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, `iotop` shows the same drops as `dstat`, see above...

Comment: @LukeLR You misunderstood me. When I/O blocks then neither `dstat` nor `iotop` should see a change. I meant: Before the pauses `iotop` should show that a lot of the writing is done to the cache.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But is there a way to confirm if the disk is still active during these zero-periods, or if it is waiting for some other bottleneck?

Comment: @LukeLR Unfortunately I do not know that. Maybe with the tools from the other answer. But another thought: If the buffers are being flushed during a pause then you would expect the size of the buffers (e.g. in `top`) to change.