# Why is overwiting a file slower than writing to a new file?

Tags: linux, performance, disk, io, fio

I noticed that sequentially overwriting an existing file may be much slower than writing a new file. Example:

```
mkdir del
cd del
fio --name=seqwrite --rw=write --ioengine=sync --bs=128KiB --size=10GiB  --fsync=10
echo "<- fio doesn't remove its temporary file, thus, compare with: "
fio --name=seqwrite --rw=write --ioengine=sync --bs=128KiB --size=10GiB  --fsync=10
```

In the second call the performance may drop by a factor of 3 or so.

What are the reasons for this?

---

Alternatively, one can also add `--overwrite=1` to `fio` to see the same effect without a previous `fio` run. Also, when repeating a non-overwrite test don't forget to remove any previous temporary files.

I tested this on xfs and ext4 in combination with a hardware RAID controller (that features a battery backed write cache) and see similar effects on both file systems. That means when writing a new file I get about 200 - 260 MB/s vs. just 70 MB/s or so when overwriting an existing file.

---

When searching the web I mainly find reports related to `bonnie++` which includes a 'rewrite' test. Those reports also show that rewriting is slower, in general.

Comment: Hmm... Do things change if you use `--end_fsync=1`? Oh and which version of `fio`? What's the actual output of fio in both cases?

Comment: @Anon, why should `--end_fsync=1` should change things? The commands already have `--fsync=10`, thus, you get at most 9 writes after the last fsync - which shouldn't make much of a difference when writing 10 GiB in total. I used fio 3.7. I don't have the fio output available right now. But I can reproduce a similar asymmetry on standard hardware with fio 3.14 when using a block-ram-device. Although the difference between both commands isn't as drastic then.

Comment: It's just a way to guarantee that all the data has been flushed by the time the job finished - you're right `fsync=10` should be syncing every ten I/Os so my suggestion is just for debugging. I can't easily explain the behaviour you're seeing (assuming your system is otherwise quiet). If you were using an SSD I might suggest you might be triggering some sort of extreme garbage collection on your second run (but you don't mention an SSD so that's a nonsense guess). I'd need to see more data (more fio output, iostat output during the run) to make better suggestions.

Comment: (A while later...) I don't know how much RAM you have on your system but I'm guessing it's more than 10 gigabytes. I've run the commands you gave as a non-root user on a system and the drop isn't nearly as dramatic... However, I was watching `/proc/meminfo` and I wonder if this is going to come down to one of the "hard things in computer science". Do things change if you issue `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` as root before you do your second run?

Comment: @Anon, regarding 'garbage collection': when executing several fio jobs in a row and deleting temporary files in between there is no drop. Regarding VM caches: I see the drop even when I directly execute fio with `--overwrite=1` i.e. without any preceding other fio run. In the original experiment no SSD was involved - just a hardware RAID controller with ~ 1 GB write cache and a mirror consisting of 2 15k RPM SAS disks. And plenty of RAM.

Comment: Re SSD - I agree. Re plenty of RAM - that's actually what I wondering is leading to this behaviour! What if evicting your cache while you overwrite is leading to the issue - when you throw away the file you are essentially dropping cached data of it. Did you run the echo command ad if so was there a change?

Comment: You can get some really low-level io statistics from iolatency and iosnoop from Brendan Gregg's perf tools, see my [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402615/119298). I hope your disks aren't part of the new "shingled" SMR [furore](https://blocksandfiles.com/2020/04/15/seagate-2-4-and-8tb-barracuda-and-desktop-hdd-smr/).

Comment: maxschlepzig: did you ever get to the bottom of this one?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to fragmentation and resolution: you need to resolve which sectors file resides in and overwrite them, in sequence, whereas writing to a new file allows to allocate continuous chunk of sectors.

Comment: Hm - the file overwritten was just created moments ago, very fast - i.e. by your reasoning it still contains of 'continuous chunk[s] of sectors' that then also should help with overwriting. Also, in case of a new file, the FS also has to resolve free sectors from some kind of free-list - which doesn't look that different.

Comment: I'm afraid I agree with @maxschlepzig. By default fio is going to issue a `fallocate()` to initially create the file which means it's quite likely (if the filesystem isn't already fragmented and the filesystem was made on a Linux from the past 10 years using defaults) that the file will be made in one big extent. You can use `filefrag` to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that evicting your cache while you are doing your overwrite is leading to the issue. If you run

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

as root before you do your overwrite does that lead to an improvement?